# How to merge a column with 2 rows to another column with only 1 row datagridview

Tags: c#

Hi i am creating a form in c# using datagridview and i have a class Option

```
public class Option
{
    public string Description;
    public string scores;
 }
```

So now i load multiple options into a datagridview and it looks like this

```
|Description|Scores|
      A       1-2
      B       3-4
      C       5-6
      D        7
```

I want to let the user be able to select the score just by clicking on the cell, but since one description can have 2 different scores the most i can do is make a seperate slider or checkbox area for them to select the score. What i wish to do is to split up the score cell into different rows depending on the score for that description. so 1 row in description might have 2 rows in the score column, is it possible? after that i will just use DGV.SelectedCell to retrieve and compute the score based on users selection

```
 |Description|Score|
 |           |  1  |
 |    A      |-----| 
 |           |  2  |
 |-----------------|
 |           |  3  |
 |    B      |-----|
 |           |  4  |
 |-----------------|
 |           |  5  |
 |     C     |-----|
 |           |  6  |
 |-----------------|
 |     D     |  7  |
 |-----------------|
```

EDIT my code

```
 Dictionary<int,Option> Question = new Dictionary<int,option>();
 //created dictionary of options for a question
 DataTable DT = new DataTable();
 DT.Columns.Add("Description");
 DT.Columns.Add("Scores");

 foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Option> item in Question)
{ DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
  Option Opt = item.Value;
  dr["Description"] = opt.Description;
  dr["Scores"] = opt.scores;
 }
```

And then i just set the DGV source to the datatable

Comment: please show your code/XAML and what you tried so far to get help

Comment: @DenisSchaf ok done, what i did so far is the same as the first table i shown, i just need to know how to split up the score into different rows

Comment: There seem to be some vague issues with both design and implementation of your code. You seem to define a class called `Option`, but refer to it as class `questione`. You combine the start and the end values of an interval in your Option/questione's `Score` property. It is not clear what valid scores are; do you only allow integers or is 1.5 a valid score as well? This all makes your issue very hard to understand and almost impossible to answer correctly.

Comment: @BartHofland sorry when denis told me to include the code i was referring to my own code in the program but forgot to change it to the way i named the classes in my quesion when i wrote it over. also the scores are only integers and will always be integers.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the update. Suppose C would have score 5-7 and D would be gone. Do you then want to include score 6 for C in your desired result as well? (I am hinting at the fact that your data design for class `Option` might be somewhat sub-optimal...)

Comment: @BartHofland yes then c would have 3 rows for its score cell, but my data will only have a maximum of 2 different scores for the same description so it shouldnt be a problem. I designed the class based on what i know, if there is a better way please share it i would like to learn

Comment: instead of having a variable that stores scores you should store `scoreA` and `scoreB` in seperate variables

Comment: @DenisSchaf alright i will try that then, i think this multiple rows in a cell is impossible as i have serached on stack overflow even more and saw some people saying its not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on mobile and don't have an IDE so forgive me if this does not compile out of the box and you need to twerk it a bit to make it work:

```
string score = dr["Weightage"].Text;  //save current value from "Weightage"
string[] scores = score.split('-');   //splits it into 2 parts
DT.Columns.Remove("Weightage");       //remove old column
DT.Columns.Add("WeightageA");         //create new columns
DT.Columns.Add("WeightageB");
dr["WeightageA"] = scores[0];         //set column values
dr["WeightageB"] = scores[1];
```

Comment: Hi thank you but I do not want to make an extra column, i just need to have 2 rows for each of the scores in a single cell under the score column, im thinking maybe to just add  a checklistbox for each cell but i still prefer to just split up the cells for user to select and its easier for me to handle the data too if it is possible.